# index.html does not include links on browser

Tags: reactjs, blueprint

Hello in my react js project I include `<link>` 's of blueprint.js library but browser does not recognize them. Instead I import them in `index.js` file then it works. Can someone briefly explain why browser does not recognize them?

**index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./src/index.css" />
<!-- add other blueprint-*.css files here -->
<link href="./node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- blueprint-icons.css file must be included alongside blueprint.css! -->
<link href="./node_modules/@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="./node_modules/@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

**index.js**

```
import 'normalize.css'
import '@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint.css'
import '@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css';
```

when i comment out of my import `index.js` web browser does not include `link`s why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node_modules` won't exist when you [build](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/) your project, so it is outside of scope. You would only be able to reference things from the index.html that are within the `public` folder or externally (like a CDN)